# Changed the keyboard but keys are not working

Tags: laptop, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have a laptop with German keyboard layout and now changed to English layout. I opened the laptop and switched the keyboard with the newly purchased keyboard but when I turned the laptop on half the keys didn't work. The only keys that do work are Winkey, R, F, Right Shift. Rest of them don't work at all.

[Photo of both keyboard - top is old german layout and bottom is the new English one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBYUV.jpg)

I am wondering if the keyboard is faulty or it's the layout mismatch. If so help me resolve this issue. Thanks

The laptop is Sony VAIO VGN-FW51ZF laptop

Comment: does it work with another computer?

Comment: No I wouldn't be able to determine that. This particular keyboard is specific to my laptop model number and I do not have another machine to test it on

Comment: I would recommend you check if you've connected the internal ribbon cables properly. It seems like it could be a connectivity issue (a loose connection in the cable that connects your new keyboard to the laptop mainboard).

Comment: Yes I checked that and ensured that there is proper contact. The fault is indeed in the component and I've issued a replacement in Amazon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom keyboard is a US keyboard, not a UK one.

If you are loading the UK driver, it has an extra key like the german one.  There is a £ above the 3, The key in the german kbd has \ and | on it.

Try loading the US keyboard driver, not the UK one.

Comment: I tried removing the keyboard driver and let windows re-install it on it's own. Now some of the keys work but there is still some contacts problem. I think the keyboard maybe defective. I'll have to check. Thanks a ton